# Rethrow checked exception from Runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, runnable

I execute multiple tasks from my main class:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(N);
    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    executor.execute(task);
}

executor .shutdown(); 
while (!executor.isTerminated()){} //block
```

task is a class that `implements Runnable`.

in `run()` method, I call some api with checked exception, meaning I need to surround the call with try-catch block.
So, there is no way for my main class to know that exception was thrown.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do your tasks return any value?

Comment: No, nothing is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Callable instead:

```
Callable<?> task = new Callable<Void> () {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        someCodeThatThrowsCheckedExceptions();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Future<?> f = executor.submit(task);
try {
    f.get();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    System.out.println("task threw exception: " + e.getCause().getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Always rethrow the exceptions letting the caller know about it else exception may just escape. you can find good explanation in the book Java Concurrency in Practice. Sorry, I should put it as a comment for you, but my score doesn't permit me:)

Comment: you can not rethrow exception from runnable.

Comment: @yuris: Yes you can: Wrap them in some RuntimeException.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an [UncheckedException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) out of the main exception. Assuming you have created your own `UncheckedException` class which extends `RuntimeException`, defining all the required constructors. You can say,

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            //some code that throws checked exception
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            throw new UncheckedException(e);
        }
    }
```

This code will compile since there is no need of `throws` declaration here

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify your task to implement `Callable`, you can throw a checked exception from call()
Since your tasks don't return a value, use `Callable<Void>`

```
class Task implements Callable<Void> {
    public Void call throws YourAPIException {
        //code that throws a checked exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

`Callable<?>` differs from `Runnable` in that it can throw a checked exception and return a result

The method signature of `call()` allows you to throw a checked exception

```
V call() throws Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

The good-looking solution, according to me, is to implement [`Callable<V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) instead of `Runnable`. The two main differences are that `Callable` can throw checked exceptions and that it may return a value. You can overcome returning a *value* by implementing `Callable<Void>`.

What you need to do:

1. Have your task implement `Callable<Void>` instead of `Runnable` - change `void run()` to `Void call() throws Exception`. No need to try/catch checked exceptions. Add `return null;` statement.
2. Use `Future<Void> checkableResult = ExecutorService.submit(Callable<Void>)`
3. You can check if it threw an exception by calling `checkableResult.get()`, which throws an [`ExecutionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) if it did. The original exception can be retrieved by [`getCause()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause%28%29). Note especially that `get()` is blocking - so periodic checks for `Callable.isDone()` is probably what you want (otherwise you might as well run it in the same thread).

Another option is to build the functionality into your `Runnable` (`volatile boolean isDone` and a `volatile Exception exception`) - but why reinvent the wheel?