# Signaling for exception from Callable thread without blocking in main thread

Tags: java, multithreading, future, callable

This is a followup for my previous question [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16957592/rethrow-checked-exception-from-runnable)

Now the problem is that I can't "block" (Future.get) in my main thread because it must continue with its work, but I do need the threads to signal it some how...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just call `Future.isDone()` periodically from your main thread, and if done, `Future.get()` the result ? That will throw the original exception.

Comment: hmmm, i will try that. btw the main thread reads from a thread-safe queue that the working-threads fill via loop so i can check it there i think.

Comment: There is some issue with that, I have an exception but isDone is false. well the problem is the main thread is stuck in another place: BlockingQueue.take()